# Call a function with conditions in argument

Tags: c#

I am trying to use `<TKey>` in a function. I don't know how to use it properly as I discovered that recently.

Here is what I tried :

```
private void filterContour()
{
    if (this.geometryRepToDraw.Profile.Famille == "FLAT")
    {
        filterContour2(x => x[0].Face == 0);
    }
    else
    {
        filterContour2(x => x[0].Face == 0 || x[0].Face==1);
    }
}
private void filterContour2<TKey>(Func<List<Contour>, TKey> selector)
{
    this.internalContours = this.internalContours.Where(selector).ToList();
}
```

But cannot decompile, as I have the error `cannot convert from <List<Contour>,Tkey> to <List<Contour>,bool>`

For information, `this.internalContours` is a `List<List<Contour>>`

I also tried to replace `Func<List<Contour>, TKey>` by `Func<List<Contour>, bool>`, but error is when calling the function (and I don't think this is the good one)?

Comment: So you don't need to use TKey here because a where clause is always going to expect a boolean as the return type. I changed your Signature to 

filterContour2(Func<List<Contour>, bool> selector)

And it worked just fine.

Comment: @Delta Great, I also had to remove method signature like that `private void filterContour2(Func<List<Contour>, bool> selector)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# `<TKey>` signifies that a generic type (labeled 'TKey') is attributed to the function (usually somewhere in the funciton signature). This allows you, to write one function definition for multiple types, unlike in function overloading where you would have to write a definition for each overloaded type. Since the compiler has no way of knowing what kind of type you might pass to `filterContour2<TKey>(...)` it has no idea if it should be able to compile it or not.

In your case you are using a selector predicate with a return type of `bool` therefore you don't need a generic function. This should be what you are looking for:

```
private void filterContour2(Func<List<Contour>, bool> selector)
{
    this.internalContours = this.internalContours.Where(selector).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes in fact found thanks to Delta's comment. Thanks for explaination.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that you need to include the Func in the method signature.

Try changing the method signature to:

```
private void filterContour2(Func<List<Contour>, bool> selector)
```

I am taking a wild guess here…